Error "Cannot find module" when using next-sitemap with TypeScript module
I'm trying to generate a sitemap for my Next.js project using the next-sitemap package. However, I'm running into issues when trying to import a TypeScript module in my next-sitemap.config.js file.
Here’s my project structure:
C:\Git\app-landing\
├── sanity\
│   ├── sanity-utils.ts
│   └── sanity-utils.js (compiled output)
├── next-sitemap.config.js
├── tsconfig.json 

tsconfig.json:
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    },
    "target": "ES2017"
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts",
    "components/landing/slider.tsx",
    "components/blog/blogContent.tsx",
    "next.config.mjs"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

Next sitemap :
const { getTools } = require("./sanity/sanity-utils");

module.exports = {
  siteUrl: process.env.SITE_URL || "https://app.net",
  generateRobotsTxt: true,
  exclude: ["/studio"],
  transform: async (config, path) => {
    const priorityMap = {
      "/": 0.9,
      "/blogs": 0.9,
      "/contact": 0.9,
      "/tools": 0.9,
      "/documents": 0.9,
      "/documents/legal-notice": 0.1,
      "/documents/gdpr": 0.1,
      "/documents/disclaimer": 0.1,
      "/documents/terms-and-conditions": 0.1,
    };

    const priorityValue = priorityMap[path] || config.priority || 0.7;

    return {
      loc: path,
      changefreq: config.changefreq || "daily",
      priority: priorityValue,
      lastmod: config.autoLastmod ? new Date().toISOString() : undefined,
      alternateRefs: config.alternateRefs || [],
    };
  },
  additionalPaths: async (config) => {
    const tools = await getTools();

    return tools.map((tool) => ({
      loc: `/tool/${tool.slug}`,
      changefreq: "daily",
      priority: 0.7,
      lastmod: new Date().toISOString(),
    }));
  },
};


The error:

✨ [next-sitemap] Loading next-sitemap config: file:///C:/Git/app-landing/next-sitemap.config.js
 ❌ [next-sitemap] Error: Cannot find module './sanity/sanity-utils'
Require stack:
- C:\Git\app-landing\next-sitemap.config.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1224:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1050:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Git\app-landing\next-sitemap.config.js:2:22)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1480:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1564:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1287:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:12)
    at cjsLoader (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:318:15) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'C:\\Git\\app-landing\\next-sitemap.config.js' ]
}


It appears that Node.js cannot locate the compiled sanity-utils.js module. I've confirmed that the file exists at the specified path. How can I correctly import this module in my next-sitemap.config.js?

Were you able to resolve this issue?
